# JavaFx Animation timer stop within itself- Possible?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using an Animation timer.
It runs two functions. One moves my objects and the other checks if my objects collide. If there is a collision my second function returns true. All this is fine. However, I cannot stop the animation timer.

ERROR:
Variable MyTimer may not have been initialised.
Which makes sense if my objects collide before the animation timer has started (when they spawn - this will never happen but it wont run anyway). Is there a way I can get around this?

UPDATE

this.stop(); Works perfectly Thanks @fabian

Comment: where is your variable `collision`, and what condition did you give it? how did you calculate the collision?

Comment: shouldn't `collision = true` be `collision == true`?

Comment: It is in my function that checks if two objects are colliding. All this code is fine its just stopping the animation so that i can change the scene. The collision returns only true or false which works if I take out the MyTimer.stop() and replace it with a print statement.

Comment: @Gabriel Anyway it would not have compiled he just forgot it here

Comment: Just call `stop()`? Can you create an actual example that compiles and post it?

Comment: We need more information, how did you write your animation?

Comment: You want to call it from the handle method? Why not use `this.stop()` or simply `stop()`?

Comment: "JUST AN EXAMPLE NOT REAL CODE", and you're asking about compile errors. So how are we supposed to tell the difference between your actual mistakes, and things that you consider pseudocode? Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.stop();

Worked perfectly as the animation timer does not have to be initialised which solves my problem.